# How can HTTP requests be divided into few parts?

Tags: http, request, webserver

I'm building an HTTP web-server that handle http requests and return responses as needed.
I need to handle cases where a HTTP requests can be divided into few parts.
Is there any format that a http request can be divided?
For example: {Request-Line}{headers}{body}? or {Request-Line,headers}{body} ?

Comment: School assignment? Have a look at RFC 7230.